# Generic hashmap in Go

Tags: generics, go

I'm trying to make a wrapper in go for the `map` type so that I can add some methods like `contains()` (this almost makes me miss Java). However, I don't know if I can do anything like generics in Java.

While almost everything I've read says that Go doesn't have generic types, there must be a better way than writing a separate struct for every single possible combination of structs and values that I'm using.

Here's what I'm trying to do, even though the code doesn't work:

```
func newMap(key interface{}, val interface{}) {
    keytype := key.(type)
    valtype := val.(type)

    return hashmap{map[keytype]valtype}
}

type hashmap struct {
    hashmap     map[]
}
```

Any help/explanation on how to do this would be appreciated.

EDIT: `Contains` isn't the only thing I'm trying to replicate, hence the desire to make a "generic" hashmap. `replace()`, `isEmpty()`, all that fun stuff as well.

Comment: Contains on a map is `_, ok := m[key]`.   Are there other methods that you want to add?

Comment: @ThunderCat isEmpty, replace, basically everything that a java hashmap has.

Comment: isEmpty: `len(m) == 0`.

Comment: Do you actually need "everything a java hashmap has" or are you just trying to recreate a Java class in Go because you think you might need those methods at some point?

Comment: The commonly used Java methods translate to simple Go expressions and statements.  isEmpty: `len(m) == 0`,  replace: `if _, ok := m[key]; ok { m[key] = newV }`

Comment: I actually do need most of those methods. All the ones that I mentioned in the question, definitely, and maybe a couple more, although I'm not 100% sure about those "couple more" yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golang does not have generics, as you say.

But the maps can be declared using your own types, so you don't necessarily need to write your own "generic" hashmap to use things like "contains" or "is empty".

Example (assuming some Icon and Colour types already exist, as well as the `GetTheIcon` function that returns some icon):

```
// this one will map Icon -> Colour
iconToColours := make(map[Icon]Colour)

myIcon := GetTheIcon()
// second return argument is true if the key was found in the map
_, iconIsContained := iconToColours[myIcon]

// check if the map is empty
isEmpty := (len(iconToColours) == 0)
```

See more here:

https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action

Answer (score 1):

Notwithstanding that a Go `map` already supports arbitrary types and some basic constructs as outlined in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50687121/4108803), starting with Go 1.18 you can actually write a generic map type, with an arbitrary method set:

```
type Map[K comparable, V any] map[K]V

func (m Map[K,V]) Contains(key K) bool {
    _, ok := m[key]
    return ok
}

func (m Map[K,V]) GetDefault(key K, dft V) V {
    if v, ok := m[key]; ok {
        return v
    }
    return dft
}

func (m Map[K,V]) PutAll(m2 map[K]V) {
    for k, v := range m2 {
        m[k] = v
    }
}
```

The nice thing about using a generic map type is that it will naturally support the usual operations as indexing and builtin functions (`make`, `delete`, ...), so you don't have to redefine those, and instead focus on methods with actual logic:

```
func main() {
    // make and index as usual
    m := make(Map[string, int], 0)
    m["foo"] = 1
    m["bar"] = 2

    fmt.Println(m.Contains("foo"))         // true
    fmt.Println(m.Contains("baz"))         // false
    fmt.Println(m.GetDefault("baz", 200))  // 200

    m2 := Map[string, int]{"a": 10, "b": 20}
    m.PutAll(m2)
    fmt.Println(m)                         // map[a:10 b:20 bar:2 foo:1]
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/PmBOdnAMD1_R

Answer (score -2):

To create functions like contains for maps, you do not need generics. Go can handle this very well, there are more ways to do this, depending on use case some ways can have better performance. You can, for example, consider writing a hashcode function

But there is something more to it to consider.

In Java generics is just code sugar. In runtime, maps or lists in Java have the same functionality as in Golang. The object which becomes visible in a map-action will have features that belong to that object. This is the same in Java and Golang. So in golang you don't have the syntactic sugar, so you have to remember yourself which objects you can excpect in maps, lists, etc.

Read here about syntactic sugar in Java. It will help you accept the choices the Go-designers made.

https://www.cordinc.com/blog/2010/09/java-generics-are-not-real-gen.html

Comment: Problem with that is, in Java I can write a class to be generic, and not have to rewrite it 50 times for 50 different types. If I had to make a new prefix tree class for every single type I put into it, for example, then that'd be a huge issue. Hence, java generics may not be "real", but they're definitely still useful. It doesn't matter how the compiler understands generics, the point is to not rewrite the *exact same thing* for every potential instance, and that's a very valuable thing to have.

Comment: Of course generics is useful, else it would not exist, although, I do not miss them very much in Go.  You solve problems in another way in Go. There are different philosophies behind the design of Go. Generics are left out with reason. But it takes a complete blog instead of a few lines comment to explain that, and it is already explained many times. Just google for "generic in go". Take a look and you find why, and also you can find replacements. Good luck,

Comment: Qk, one example. In Java you create a list with a type-generic, and in this way you can use the items of the list as that type. In Go you work with slices instead, and they are already of a specific type. So you can use the items of the slice as that type. To be more generic, if desired, you can make slices of interfaces instead of structs, and in this way you can put more types of structs in a slice, as long as the same interface is applicable. There are also type-assertions to be more type specific if needed. See? But there is more to explain. Work with it, you will learn. It is fun..